# C# MVC add parameter to filter a MVCGrid but the url display the query string false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I add a parameter to my Url it displays the '?' and '='as '%3f' and '%3d'

```
 Index/%3fgrid-filter%3dName__1__searchname
```

what i need should look like this:

```
Index/?grid-filter=Name__1__searchname
```

I have a form, where i can insert a new User. Once i click the save button, it should redirect to the grid and call the filter with the name from the user.

Controller-Save():

```
string newUrl ="?grid-filter=Name__1__" + user.Name;
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = newUrl});
```

I tried Uri.EncodeUriString and so on but the url didnt change. I found some similar questions to, but none worked for me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `var filter = "Name__1__" + user.Name; return RedirectToAction("Index", new { grid-filter = filter });`

Comment: he didnt know  grid-filter. i got a error message

Comment: It would need to be `grid_filter` (underscore, not hyphen)

Comment: ok i can redirect now to the view but the grid didnt filter for the name.It shows still all entries. Url now: /Index?grid_filter=Name__1__test12 with /Index?grid-filter=Name__1__test12 it works. so i think the error is the underscore now in the Url

Comment: You have not shown any code for you `Index()` or how your filtering your data (how could anyone guess what your doing)

Comment: Sry i updated now with the code of the index side and the grid-view i hope that helps

Comment: You have not shown you `Index()` method (just some view code which does not appear to have anything to do with filtering your data)

Comment: I updated. and thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: The only problem is that the url show grid_filter with a underscore and not with a minus in the url. with the minus it works

Comment: No where in your `Index()` method do you even access the value that you passing to it (the method would need to be `Index(string grid_filter)` and nowhere do you ever use it so its impossible to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: I want only if i cklick a button that it redirect me to the grid view with an filter.So if i click on this button the grid should only show the entry of the selected filter(the mvc grid filter works with that parameters but only with the minus between grid and filter). In this case it would work if the url looks like  ?grid-filter=Name__1__" but with your solution its looks like ?grid_filter=Name__1__". So the only differnt is the underscore between grid and filter. So my question is now how can i say that it should make a "-" instead of the underscore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for helping. 
It works with this code

```
 filter = "Name__1__" + name.Name;
    var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                        dictionary.Add("grid-filter", filter);                 
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", dictionary);
```

So the url displays the parameter right:

```
/Index?grid-filter=Name__1__tttttttt
```